# JavaScript error when using ASP.NET UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, asp.net-3.5

I'm using an `UpdatePanel` to swap the `ActiveView` of a `MultiView`.

In IE6, 7 and 8 and Chrome 7 I get a JavaScript error when the UpdatePanel returns. In Firefox 3.6.1 there is no error reported (in the error console or in Firebug).

The error is on line 3621 of ScriptResource.axd

```
function Sys$_ScriptLoader$_loadScriptsInternal() {
    var session = this._currentSession;
    if (session.scriptsToLoad && session.scriptsToLoad.length > 0) {
        var nextScript = Array.dequeue(session.scriptsToLoad);
        var scriptElement = this._createScriptElement(nextScript);

        if (scriptElement.text && Sys.Browser.agent === Sys.Browser.Safari) {
            scriptElement.innerHTML = scriptElement.text;
            delete scriptElement.text;
        }            
        if (typeof(nextScript.src) === "string") {
            this._currentTask = new Sys._ScriptLoaderTask(scriptElement, this._scriptLoadedDelegate);
            this._currentTask.execute();
        }
        else {
            var headElements = document.getElementsByTagName('head');
            if (headElements.length === 0) {
                 throw new Error.invalidOperation(Sys.Res.scriptLoadFailedNoHead);
            }
            else {
line 3621:        headElements[0].appendChild(scriptElement);
            }


            Sys._ScriptLoader._clearScript(scriptElement);
            this._loadScriptsInternal();
        }
    }
    else {
        this._stopSession();
        var callback = session.allScriptsLoadedCallback;
        if(callback) {
            callback(this);
        }
        this._nextSession();
    }
}
```

[image: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number]

Chrome's Developer tools show that `headElements` is a `NodeList` with one element and that `scriptElement` is an `HTMLScriptElement`
[image: NodeList and ScriptElement]

What could be the cause of this error? Why is it only apparent in IE and Chrome, and not Firefox?

Comment: Most likely, something in the code. Can you share the code where you are doing the swapping?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was an error in the script that I was outputting in the `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript`. This was causing a runtime error as the browser parsed the JavaScript when the `<script>` tag was added to the DOM, as suggested by @Rahul in the comments.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this question and the answer. I was missing an apostrophe `'` in my script which in fact led to a number sitting there in a syntactically wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

gzip compression might also cause this kind of issue for those looking for a solution.